# AC not blowing cool air, Contractor said HVAC unit is perfectly fine and that it has to do with my smart thermostat (Ecobee 3)

Tags: hvac, thermostat, air-conditioning, cooling, central-air

So basically I changed out the filter on my HVAC unit (National Comfort Products, Model CPG41238-U23) and after I did that the AC stopped blowing out cold air. It was working completely fine until I changed the filter on the HVAC unit. The HVAC is relatively new and was installed August 2019. Had a contractor come and take a look and he checked every component of the HVAC unit and said that there is absolutely nothing wrong with the HVAC unit. He said that there is something wrong with my smart thermostat (Ecobee 3). He said that sometimes smart thermostats randomly turn off the system and that likely it will randomly come back on. He said to wait until Monday morning and see if it starts to work. Until then he is letting the HVAC unit run without a filter. He said if it starts to work then I can go ahead and put the filter back in. Does it make sense that my Ecobee 3 randomly is stopping my HVAC from blowing cool air? If so, is there anything I can do to troubleshoot the thermostat to get it to blow cool air again before monday morning? Thanks in advance for any help. I've attached a couple pictures of what the thermostat is saying and pictures of the wiring.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNJ49.jpg

Comment: I would just yank the thermostat and short the cooling wire (Y) to common (R), which will kick it on instantly. Also, don't run the AC w/o a filter; it will gunk up the coils and reduce efficiency.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Would moving the Y wire to RC be a permanent fix though? Also on the Ecobee website it says that the Y terminal must be connected, "Remove the ecobee from the wall and confirm that you have a wire inserted into the Y1 terminal. This terminal is responsible for engaging your outdoor compressor, so you will need to have your Y wire securely connected to this terminal for your air conditioning to work. Give the wire a gentle tug to ensure that it's secure."

Comment: That's just to test that your AC works w/o waiting.